# What does the emblem on Bolt's jacket mean?

Tags: naruto

Emblem at the jacket's back usually have some sort of clan connection:

[image: The Uchiha crest]

In the last chapter of Naruto, Bolt sports a previously unseen emblem on his jacket:

[image: Bolt after class is dismissed]

Whose emblem is that? Does this emblem mean anything?

Comment: quite possibly it's a new clan symbol for the union of the Hyūga and Uzumaki/Namikaze/Senju Clans (assuming the last one since Uzumaki are distant blood relative to Senju)

Comment: That's the same symbol on Megaman's helmet in Megaman Starforce.![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LU59K.png)

Answer (score 4):

Though it is not explicitly mentioned, that **new emblem** is most likely the combination of Hyūga and Uzumaki/Namikaze Clan.